# Defining a dependency that is not one of the input parameters for a UDF?

Tags: excel, vba, input, parameters, dependencies

In short: Is there a way to define a dependency that is not one of the input parameters for a UDF?

This is my first post here. I'm learning VBA in Excel and I've seen a large number of very talented coders posting here, so here it goes:

I want to know how to make a UDF that depends on a cell range, but the user does not have to input this cell range. A simple example would be a function that always takes cell "A1" and concatenates the input to A1 as the output. If the range was statically referenced inside a UDF, then when cell "A1" is erased by the user, the range wouldn't turn into "#REF".

If A1 = "Hello", and then the input is " World", I want the output to be "Hello World".

I thought maybe I could call a function within a function and the dependency tree would build based on that (see below), but my test function won't update unless I change the input parameter for the first function called (in1).

Test code:

```
Public Function test(in1 As String) As String
    test = testdep(in1, Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1"))
End Function

Private Function testdep(in1 As String, rng As Range)
    testdep = rng.Value & in1
End Function
```

Ideas?

Edit1: To be more specific, I want the function to update the output value when cell "A1" is changed, even though cell A1 is not an input parameter.
E.g. I change A1 to now be "blah" instead of "Hello", then the value would update to "blah World". I would make the function volatile, but I have a lot of functions like that and the calculation speed gets very groggy.

Comment: Thanks @Charles-Williams, I'm going to look into the Worksheet_Change event.

Answer (score 0):

There are only 2 ways I know of to make a UDF recalculate when an a cell changes that is used inside the UDF but is not in the parameter list:
- make the UDF volatile
- set workbook.forcefullcalculation to true

Both of these solutions make the the udf calculate at every calculation: force full calculation is even more drastic - it switches off smart recalc and makes every formula calculate

Comment: 3rd way: the Worksheet_Change event can be checked to see if A1 is the cell changed, and recalculate the dependent cell

Answer (score -1):

You don't need to specify anything as parameter. Something like this works like a charm:

```
Public Function CombineHelloAndWorld() As String
    CombineHelloAndWorld = Range("A1") & " " & Range("A2")
End Function
```

Let's say you have "Hello" in `[A1]` and "World" in `[A2]`. In cell `[A3]` you write `=CombineHelloAndWorld()` and it gives you "Hello World".

Also if `Application.Calculation` is set to `xlCalculationAutomatic`, it will automaticly change `[A3]` if you change either `[A1]` or `[A2]`

Comment: Carlos, This does not work with Automatic calculation because there are no dependencies.